# Postgresql track serial by ID in another column

Tags: postgresql

So I am trying to create a database that can store videos from products, but I do intend to add a few million of them. So obviously I want the performance to be as good as possible.

I wanted to achieve the following:

```
BIGINT     | SMALLSERIAL | VARCHAR(30)
product_id | video_id    | video_hash
1            1             Dkfjoie124
1            2             POoieqlgkQ
1            3             Xd2t9dakcx
2            1             Df2459Afdw
```

However, when I insert a new video for a product:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (product_id, video_hash) VALUES (2, DSpewirncS)
```

I want the following to happen:

```
BIGINT     | SMALLSERIAL | VARCHAR(30)
product_id | video_id    | video_hash
1            1             Dkfjoie124
1            2             POoieqlgkQ
1            3             Xd2t9dakcx
2            1             Df2459Afdw
2            2             DSpewirncS
```

Will this happen when I set the column type for `video_id` to `SMALLSERIAL`? Because I am afraid that it will insert a different value (the highest in the entire column), which I do not want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a serial is bound to a sequence and that doesn't reset without telling it to do.

But if you want an ordinal for the videos per products you can query the table to produce it using the `row_number()` window function.

```
SELECT product_id,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id
                          ORDER BY video_id) video_ordinal,
       video_hash
       FROM table;
```

You could also create a view for this query for convenience, so that you can query the view instead of the table and the view would look like you want it.